# Is the Poincare Birkhoff theorem valid if we change the volume form of the annulus region?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

Is the Poincare-Birkhoff theorem valid if  we change the volume form of the  annulus region?

Note: A possible  approach could be the  following: Is it true to say that the  answer is  affirmative because of  Arnold  conjecture (which is possibly true for the  annulus region)?
Is Arnold  conjecture true (or  discussable)  for  manifold  with boundary at least  in low  dimensional case?

Comment: A theorem of Jürgen Moser says that all smooth volume forms on a compact, connected, smooth manifold are equivalent by a smooth diffeomorphism.  If this theorem can be extended to manifolds with boundary (or just surfaces with boundary), that would show the Poincaré-Birkhoff theorem is true for an arbitrary smooth volume form on the closed annulus.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  Is it realy the case? if it would be true so one may  associate    an intrinsic  volum to every  manifold  M: the integral of  arbitrary volum form over M. By theorem of change of  variabble $\int_M f^* \alpha =\int M \alpha$.  But I guess the theorem of Moser has  a function multiplication too that is  $\alpha =g f^* \beta$ for  a positive function $g$. Do you agree?

Comment: @DanielAsimov I  correct a typos:  $\int_M f^* \alpha =\int_M \alpha$

Comment: So if the multiplication version of the theorem is true we can not conclude that the Poincare Birkhoff theorem is true for  arbitrary volum form. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @DanielAsimov  What is  a reference for the  Moser theorem you mentioned?

Comment: @DanielAsimov  The  tragedy is that the  Poincare Birkhoff is  about topological $[0 1]\times S^1$ but it is  not about  product metric

Comment: I should have said that for any two positive volume forms on an oriented manfold, compatible with the orientation, there is a diffeomorphism taking one to the other up to a positive constant factor (https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mabreu/GD/moser.pdf).

Comment: @DanielAsimov Yes  Perfect thank you

Comment: @DanielAsimov  BTW  may  I ask you  to look at the updated question (a relation to Arnold  conjecture)?